# Could two LAN7800s be used to create a USB3-over-Ethernet extender?

Tags: embedded, ethernet, gigabit, lan, usb-3

I am looking to create a USB 3.0 extender and am considering the possibility of using two [LAN7800](https://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/aemDocuments/documents/UNG/ProductDocuments/DataSheets/LAN7800-Data-Sheet-DS00001992H.pdf) ICs to achieve this. My goal is to achieve speeds of up to 1Gbps.

I already know that the PC will see a Network Adapter, but would it be possible to trick the PC into thinking it's communicating directly with the camera by installing the camera's driver to the PC? Would the solution shown in the picture work? Is this theoretically possible?

Furthermore, if the solution is possible, would it allow me to achieve speeds up to 1Gbps? Is this a viable solution to achieve the required transfer speeds?

[image: Usb3 extender]

Answer (score 3):

No, for many reasons. One is that the LAN7800 is an USB device. It can't be an USB host for the camera. And it can't fake to be a camera because it is an Ethernet interface.

Comment: Thanks for your input. After digging a bit deeper, I've realized that this option just isn't going to work